# php mysqli prepared statement using wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to build this prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE";
$sql .= " title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?";
$sql .= " OR content LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?";

$q = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$one = $this->term;
$two = "%" . $this->term;
$three = $this->term . "%";
$four = "%" . $this->term . "%";

$q->bind_param("ssssssss", $one, $two, $three, $four, $one, $two, $three, $four);
$q->execute();
```

$this->db is my mysqli connection object

$this->term is a user provided string.

I am not receiving any type of error as from the database. I know the sql statement works, I ran it with a $this->db->query() and it came out fine. When I run it with the prepared statement it comes back with no results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why all the testing looking for 'sth', '%sth', 'sth%' or '%sth%'? This would yield the same results as looking only for '%sth%', so you can leave your query just as `SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title LIKE '%sth%' OR content LIKE '%sth%'`

Comment: Carlos: Thank you for pointing that out. I looked at some more documentation on the wildcard search and it does match anything (including zero matches). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get it to work with a prepared statement. I moved to to a mysqli->query() and escaped the user string. Carlos, thanks for the help in fixing my query.

Answer (score 2):

To use a wildcard in a prepared statement you need to use CONCAT in your sql statement.  The database will take care of concatenating the percent signs onto your search term.

Assuming you want a wildcard at the beginning or end of your search term, your sql should look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR content LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

Comment: You *can* but you don't have to. One can add wildcards on the PHP side all right, like the OP did